# “Invalid controller specified” error in zend framework 1

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Zend Framework project previously half done by other programmers. With it another application is directly bridged into Zend's public folder under `public/hrm` folder.

The application seems to run okay. But at the apache error log I constantly find these errors.

```
  [Wed Dec 25 12:33:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (hrm)' in /path/to/proj/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248\n
  Stack trace:
  \n#0 /path/to/proj/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
  \n#1 /path/to/proj/Application/Bootstrap.php(48): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
  \n#2 /path/to/proj/public/index.php(30): Application_Bootstrap->run()
  \n#3 {main}
  \n  thrown in /path/to/proj/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php on line 248, referer: http://local.hrm.tld/hrm/lib/controllers/CentralController.php?reqcode=EMP&VIEW=MAIN&sortField=0&sortOrder0=ASC&VIEW=MAIN

  [Wed Dec 25 12:33:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (hrm)' in /path/to/proj/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248\nStack trace:
  \n#0 /path/to/proj/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
  \n#1 /path/to/proj/Application/Bootstrap.php(48): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
  \n#2 /path/to/proj/public/index.php(30): Application_Bootstrap->run()
  \n#3 {main}
  \n  thrown in /path/to/proj/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php on line 248, referer: http://local.hrm.tld/hrm/lib/controllers/CentralController.php?menu_no_top=hr&id=0008&capturemode=updatemode&reqcode=EMP&currentPage=1
```

the content of .htaccess at public folder is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You should modify your .htaccess, i think someone is trying to access some files in hrm folder that don't exist, in this case, the request gets forwarded to your application, which tries to find the hrm module or controller, since it is not there, it throws an error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(hrm)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(hrm)($|/) - [L]
```

Will make it not rewrite anything from hrm folder.

Or inside hrm/.htaccess put:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

But i assume, you need some rewriting there so this might not be the option!

Comment: Sorry for responding late.

The *hrm* folder under *public* is just a part of the main Zend application. Your extra rule allows only the *hrm*. But then the main ZF routes which worked earlier fails.

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand without actually seeing the structure. But i am guessing, if this fails ,there is no .htaccess within hrm folder, and there should be if i understood the structure right.

Comment: The solution didn't actually help directly. But I figured out the Fatal error was actually for some missing asset files. Otherwise, both the ZF app-modules and the hrm app works perfectly. I just was curious why there were errors and app was still functioning properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following line into your application.ini

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/hrm"
```